# No Module Named 'my_appdjango' while migrating django app

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I am  following this tutorial to setup my django `(v 3.0.8)` app. Below is my folder structure.

```
+my_site
    +my_app
        +migrations
            __init__.py
        __init__.py
        admin.py
        apps.py
        models.py
        tests.py
        urls.py
        views.py
    +my_site
    __init__.py
    asgi.py
    settings.py
    urls.py
    wsgi.py
manage.py
```

I have added `'my_app'` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`. But while executing command
`python manage.py makemigrations my_app` on Windows, I get the below error:

```
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_appdjango'
```

Why is it looking for `my_appdjango` when I have clearly defined `my_app`?

EDIT:
Settings.py

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'my_app'
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Comment: pls, show your settings file.

Comment: added to question @adnanmuttaleb

Comment: you are missing comma in INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: i am an idiot -_-...missed a comma

Answer (score 0):

In `settings.py` I missed a comma. So it should be like:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'ftl_app',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed a comma

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'ftl_app'`,`
   
]
```